# Why do I get the error, module object is not callable when calling csv writer using tabulate?

Tags: python, csv, cs50, sys

```
import tabulate
import sys
import csv

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        sys.exit('Too few command-line arguments')
    elif len(sys.argv) > 2:
        sys.exit('Too many command-line arguments')
    elif not sys.argv[1].endswith('.csv'):
        sys.exit('Not a CSV file')
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        try:
            with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(tabulate(writerwriter, header="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            sys.exit('File does not exist')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to print a tabulated version of an inputted csv file in the command line. It should open the file in write mode, and then re-write that file in a tabulated graph format with the header as the first line. However, when I run the graph, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/112136537/pizza/pizza.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workspaces/112136537/pizza/pizza.py", line 16, in main
    spamwriter.writerow(tabulate(spamwriter, header="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why can't the module be called?

Comment: Change `import tabulate` to `from tabulate import tabulate`, or change `tabulate(` to `tabulate.tabulate(`

Comment: I did that, but now it throws the error; TypeError: tabulate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'   after looking at tabulate's read docs, I saw that tabulate can take a header argument, so why would it throw that error?

Comment: It's `headers`, not `header`

Comment: Now throws:
TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable

Comment: Where do you define `writerwriter`?

Comment: The first argument to `tabulate()` should be the table you're trying to print. Where is the table in your code?

Comment: You should be reading from the CSV file, not writing to it.